# ReactJS - Child's onClick event calls parent method but the scope is not what I expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and child class. The parent class has a store and a method that needs to be called when the child is clicked. The parent method modifies the store. Unfortunately when I call the parent's method from the child's onClick (using props), the `this` object is not available. I believe this is a scoping issue but I don't know whether it's a JS level issue or a misunderstanding of React's scoping (I'm new to the framework).

The components are defined below, when I click on the Button span I get the following error out of toggleAlarmState:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Parent component

```
import Button from "../components/buttons/Button"

export default class TestStatus extends Component {

    state = {
        alarmIsOn: false,
    };

    toggleAlarmState(event) {
        this.setState({
                alarmIsOn: !this.state.alarmIsOn
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                className="alarm-toggle-btn"
                text={`Alarm is ${this.state.alarmIsOn ? 'On' : 'Off'}`}
                onClick={this.toggleAlarmState}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class Btn extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <span onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</span>
        )
    }
}
```

Why is `this` undefined and what is the best practice for modifying the store when I click a button component?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: You need to bind `this` https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you convert `toggleAlarmState` to an arrow function, it will work! or if you insist on using the same function, you have to bind `toggleAlarmState` with `this` inside your constructor.

```
toggleAlarmState = event => {
        this.setState({
                alarmIsOn: !this.state.alarmIsOn
            }
        )
    }
```

This is another solution with binding if you are not using an arrow function.

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.toggleAlarmState = this.toggleAlarmState.bind(this);
  }

    state = {
    alarmIsOn: false,
};

toggleAlarmState(event) {
    this.setState({
            alarmIsOn: !this.state.alarmIsOn
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: The arrow function worked like a charm. Can you explain why? If I were make a guess is it because I'm now assigning the function to a variable? Does that solidify the scope more than just defining a function?

Comment: In classic function expressions, the `this` keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which it is called. With arrow functions, however, this is lexically bound. It means that it uses this from the code that contains the arrow function. Yes, it does solidify the scope more than just defining it as a simple function. However, there are certain cases you would not want to use arrow functions. Check out this [post](https://wesbos.com/arrow-function-no-no/) to know when it's not advised to use `this`.